# What is the difference between “int” and “uint” / “long” and “ulong”?

Tags: c#, types, integer, unsigned, signed

I know about `int` and `long` (32-bit and 64-bit numbers), but what are `uint` and `ulong`?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

The primitive data types prefixed with "u" are unsigned versions with the same bit sizes. Effectively, this means they cannot store negative numbers, but on the other hand they can store positive numbers twice as large as their signed counterparts. The signed counterparts do not have "u" prefixed.

The limits for int (32 bit) are:

```
int: –2147483648 to 2147483647 
uint: 0 to 4294967295
```

And for long (64 bit):

```
long: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
ulong: 0 to 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: This is quite fun to work out by hand.  A 32-bit signed variable uses 1 bit for the sign (positive or negative) so can store values between -2^31 and +2^31 - 1

Comment: when comparing int and uint for usage, which one is feasible?

Comment: What's the c++ equivalent?

Comment: @JacoPretorius Thats wrong. 8 bit int has a range from –128 to 127. The 9th bit represents 256. So with 8 bits you can represent all values up to 255 (9th val - 1). The range from -128 to 127 has a length of exactly 255. So there is no bit that holds the sign. All values up to 127 are positive. Values above get displayed negative. 255 would be -1. 254 would be -2 and so one way down to 128.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that specifically for int vs uint, the unsigned integer is not CLS-compliant, and it's recommended to use int as often as possible.

Answer (score 47):

`uint` and `ulong` are the unsigned versions of `int` and `long`. That means they can't be negative. Instead they have a larger maximum value.

```
Type    Min                           Max                           CLS-compliant
int     -2,147,483,648                2,147,483,647                 Yes
uint    0                             4,294,967,295                 No
long    –9,223,372,036,854,775,808    9,223,372,036,854,775,807     Yes
ulong   0                             18,446,744,073,709,551,615    No
```

To write a literal unsigned int in your source code you can use the suffix `u` or `U` for example `123U`.

You should not use uint and ulong in your public interface if you wish to be [CLS-Compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.90).aspx).

Read the documentation for more information:

- [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx)
- [uint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx)
- [long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx)
- [ulong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx)

By the way, there is also [short](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx) and [ushort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbf1574z.aspx) and [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) and [sbyte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d86he86x.aspx).

Comment: This is interesting - what do you mean about CLS compliant? The link goes to the MSDN documentation for int. If by "CLS" you mean C# language spec then I don't understand - the spec clearly describes both uint and ulong (section 1.3)

Comment: @Isak Savo: It is important to be CLS-compliant if you are writing interface that could be used by other .NET languages than C#.

Comment: Curious that you mention short and ushort but leave out byte and sbyte :)

Answer (score 13):

`u` means `unsigned`, so `ulong` is a large number without sign. You can store a bigger value in `ulong` than `long`, but no negative numbers allowed.

A `long` value is stored in 64-bit,with its first digit to show if it's a positive/negative number. while `ulong` is also 64-bit, with all 64 bit to store the number. so the maximum of ulong is 2(64)-1, while long is 2(63)-1.

Answer (score 12):

The difference is that the `uint` and `ulong` are unsigned data types, meaning the range is different: They do not accept negative values:

```
int range: -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
uint range: 0 to 4,294,967,295

long range: –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
ulong range: 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers here and a little review you can understand it this way: unsigned is in reference to the assignment of a negative or positive explicit assignment (think the "-" in -1) and the inability to have negative versions of said numbers.

And because of this capacity on the negative end being removed as an option they instead allocated that capacity to the positive end hence the doubling of the positive valuation's maximum value. So instead of the bit range being split along positive and negative valuations, they are instead for ushort, uint, along, etc allocated to the positive end of the valuation.