# Difference between signed / unsigned char

Tags: c, types, unsigned

So I know that the difference between a `signed int` and `unsigned int` is that a bit is used to signify if the number if positive or negative, but how does this apply to a `char`? How can a character be positive or negative?

Comment: [A previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/unsigned-char) on this topic will help.

Comment: *"So I know that the difference between a signed and unsigned int is that a bit is used to signify if the number if positive or negative"* - Note that this is just one of the ways to to it and not the most usual and practical one.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

There's no dedicated "character type" in C language. `char` is an integer type, same (in that regard) as `int`, `short` and other integer types. `char` just happens to be the smallest integer type. So, just like any other integer type, it can be signed or unsigned.

It is true that (as the name suggests) `char` is mostly intended to be used to represent characters. But characters in C are represented by their integer "codes", so there's nothing unusual in the fact that an integer type `char` is used to serve that purpose.

The only general difference between `char` and other integer types is that plain `char` is not synonymous with `signed char`, while with other integer types the `signed` modifier is optional/implied.

Comment: Alright, hopefully you'll be able to stay with me here, I'm not that great with bits / C and stuff. So with a signed char, something like "01011011" could represent one character?

Comment: @Chiggins: Is it binary? If so, then yes. Your `01011011` is a binary representation of 91. So, it represents whatever character has code 91 on your platform (`[` on PC, for example).

Comment: For a simple proof of the nature of chars being ints try applying `swtich...case`, which can be applied only to integral numeric values.

Comment: C89 6.1.2.5 "There are three character types, designated as char , signed char, and unsigned char."

C11 6.2.5p15 "The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called the *character types*." 6.2.5fn45 "`char` is a separate type from the other two and is not compatible with either"

Answer (score 71):

I slightly disagree with the above. The `unsigned char` simply means: Use the most significant bit instead of treating it as a bit flag for +/- sign when performing arithmetic operations.

It makes significance if you use `char` as a number for instance:

```
typedef char BYTE1;
typedef unsigned char BYTE2;

BYTE1 a;
BYTE2 b;
```

For variable `a`, only 7 bits are available and its range is (-127 to 127)  = (+/-)2^7 -1.
For variable `b` all 8 bits are available and the range is 0 to 255 (2^8 -1).

If you use `char` as character, "unsigned" is completely ignored by the compiler just as comments are removed from your program.

Comment: I think you did a mistake (correct me if I'm wrong):    
"a" is signed char so the range is -128 to 127   and  
"b" is unsigned char so the range is 0 to 255.    
[similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char)

Comment: You need to change this answer to reflect that signed integers use twos complement and not a sign bit like you say, because as it stands this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Matthew Mitchell read the question again. He didn't want a thesis on that. simple questions deserve simple answers.. I don't over complicating things to impress others!

Comment: as written above, this is not what the standard says. Being unsigned could in principal only mean "ignore the sign bit". Nothing guarantees that an unsigned type will be able to hold larger positive value than its signed counterpart.

Comment: @user1251840 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724242/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-uint-long-and-ulong

Comment: **This is incorrect**. In C, signed integer types use two's complement, with range `-(2^n-1)` to `(2^n-1)-1`, where `n` is the number of bits and `0` is counted once, not twice. By default, a `char` is unsigned, not signed. Please correct this; it is a simple **but incorrect** explanation.

Comment: The signed bit also **does not change the way arithmetic works**, adding the two unsigned numbers 4294967295 and 4294967295 will still give you a signed -2.  Type is **only** for humans and has no meaning at a binary level.

Comment: Quick correction to the above: comparisons are changed depending on whether it is signed or unsigned.

Comment: wizzwizz4: AFAIK **if char is unsigned or signed by default is defined by the implementation** not by the standard (e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/138526)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The C standard does not define the encoding format for signed integers. It is up to the compiler designer to choose between 2s complement, 1s complement and sign & magnitude.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 As far as my understanding of the C11 standard goes, the actual smallest value *is* -127. So you can end up with no -128. See Section 5.2.4.2.1.

Comment: @Garogolun You are right, I think. I've deleted one of my comments, but I'm not sure enough to delete the other.

Comment: I'm here a bit late, but if I remember my undergrad course 2s complement makes the math a bit easier, but doesn't affect the storage capacity of the int. Saying the answer is incorrect only because of that seems a bit pedantic, as the veracity of the answer does not depend on the way you encode your int.

Answer (score 29):

There are three char types: (plain) `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`.  Any char is usually an 8-bit integer* and in that sense, a `signed` and `unsigned char` have a useful meaning (generally equivalent to `uint8_t` and `int8_t`).  When used as a character in the sense of text, use a `char` (also referred to as a plain char).  This is typically a `signed char` but can be implemented either way by the compiler.

* Technically, a char can be any size as long as `sizeof(char)` is 1, but it is usually an 8-bit integer.

Comment: "There are three char types" - That only applies to C++.

Comment: @Martin It applies to C in even greater degree than to C++

Answer (score 19):

Representation is the same, the meaning is different. e.g, 0xFF, it both represented as "FF". When it is treated as "char", it is negative number -1; but it is 255 as unsigned. When it comes to bit shifting, it is a big difference since the sign bit is not shifted. e.g, if you shift 255 right 1 bit, it will get 127; shifting "-1" right will be no effect.

Comment: Note that the behavior of a right bitshift on a signed type is actually implementation defined. "Most" compilers will shift `-1` to `/-1` but you could actually also get `10111111`

Answer (score 15):

A `signed char` is a signed value which is typically smaller than, and is guaranteed not to be bigger than, a `short`.  An `unsigned char` is an unsigned value which is typically smaller than, and is guaranteed not to be bigger than, a `short`.  A type `char` without a `signed` or `unsigned` qualifier may behave as either a signed or unsigned `char`; this is usually implementation-defined, but there are a couple of cases where it is not:

1. If, in the target platform's character set, any of the characters required by standard C would map to a code higher than the maximum `signed char`, then `char` must be unsigned.

   If `char` and `short` are the same size, then `char` must be signed.

Part of the reason there are two dialects of "C" (those where `char` is signed, and those where it is unsigned) is that there are some implementations where `char` *must* be unsigned, and others where it *must* be signed.

Answer (score 2):

The same way -- e.g. if you have an 8-bit char, 7 bits can be used for magnitude and 1 for sign. So an unsigned char might range from 0 to 255, whilst a signed char might range from -128 to 127 (for example).

Answer (score 2):

This because a `char` is stored at all effects as a 8-bit number. Speaking about a negative or positive `char` doesn't make sense if you consider it an ASCII code (which can be just signed*)  but makes sense if you use that `char` to store a number, which could be in range 0-255 or in -128..127 according to the 2-complement representation.

*: it can be also unsigned, it actually depends on the implementation I think, in that case you will have access to extended ASCII charset provided by the encoding used

Answer (score 1):

The same way how an `int` can be positive or negative. There is no difference. Actually on many platforms unqualified `char` is signed.