# Compiler warnings, fixed but would like to make sure I understand

Tags: c, windows, gcc, codeblocks

I have been using some C code I found online, which had compiler warnings with codeblocks on windows 7, as I am learning C and trying to understand the code as part of the learning process I decided to look at the warnings and fix them a few where simple enough, however the first block I fixed I think I understand, but would be grateful if someone could confirm my understanding, the original code snippet in question is

`unsigned char buffer[MAX_PATH];`

```
unsigned char text_to_send[MAX_PATH];

unsigned char digits[MAX_PATH];
```

// example warning with digits when used as below

```
text_to_send[m] = strtol(digits, NULL, 16);
```

The warning given is

warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'strtol' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]|

with a note 
note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'unsigned char *'

The warning and note is correct to my understanding as digits used on it's own is a constant pointer to the address of digits[0].  When I remove the unsigned declarations and leave them as just type char, the compiler no longer issues warnings when these 3 arrays are used.

My question is that I can see no reason to use unsigned char digits[MAX_PATH] (or for the two declarations which give similar errors], but am I missing something, does the original author know something I have missed?

The code now compiles warning free and works seemingly the same, any input greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337217/difference-between-signed-unsigned-char

Comment: `unsigned char text_to_send[MAX_PATH]; text_to_send[m] = strtol(digits, NULL, 16);` That doesn't give a warning? "unsigned char = long"?

Comment: No, it does not give an error, but I do see what you mean, I will look at that one also, it can't be right. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C language `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are three different, incompatible types. It is true that in specific implementations the representation of `char` will coincide with that of either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, but that still does not make these types compatible.

This, in turn, means that, regardless of implementation's properties, a pointer of type `unsigned char *` cannot be implicitly converted to type `char *`. These types are also incompatible. An attempt to perform such implicit conversion is a *constraint violation*, i.e. it is what we usually call an *error* (as opposed to what we usually call a *warning*).

That is what the compiler is trying to tell you with that diagnostic message.

Answer (score 0):

`strtol()` takes a `char *`; you're passing it an `unsigned char*`. The C Standard says that whether a vanilla `char` is an `unsigned char` or a `signed char` An implementation choice. Hence the compiler whine.

It's good practice to set your MS C options to use sane [unsigned] chars via its [`/J` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d294k5z.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned using gcc with codeblocks, I do understand why the warning is there, my question is more why would you declare it unsigned in the first place.

Comment: Because a `char` is an integer. A `signed char` used as an index into an array, for instance, cause problems for codepoints above 0x7F, since it will be a negative index into the array, causing memory corruption or access violations. For the sake of portability and to minimize unwanted problems, explicity declare your `char` types as 'signed' or 'unsigned'.

Comment: In any case, still `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three different types, not compatible with each other. Even in implementations where `char` is unsigned, `char` is still considered incompatible with `unsigned char`. This means that regardless of implementation, `char *` and `unsigned char *` are incompatible pointer types, which cannot be mixed.