# what is unsigned char array and how to declare and initialize it

Tags: c

I need to declare an unsigned char array in a c program. However I am not fully aware what it takes to do that. I mean I have tried declaring char array like
char abc[];
but what makes it unsigned char array?
and also what does char * abc[]; would mean?

Comment: `unsigned char arr[] = {100, 200};`

Comment: Googlize it before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between signed / unsigned char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337217/difference-between-signed-unsigned-char)

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of 10 unsigned chars:

```
unsigned char abc[10];
```

This is an array of 10 signed chars:

```
signed char abc[10];
```

If you don't explicitly say `signed` or `unsigned`, then it is implementation defined if this is an array of 10 signed chars or 10 unsigned chars:

```
char abc[10];
```

Note that for other types, like `int` or `long`, if you don't explicitly say `unsigned`, they will be signed numbers.

Comment: Note that (plain) `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three different types, albeit that two cover the same range (and which two is implementation defined).