# Does the standard guarantee that uint8_t, int8_t, and char are all unique types?

Tags: c++, char, language-lawyer, cstdint

It seems the following is guaranteed to pass (asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337217/difference-between-signed-unsigned-char)):

```
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<char, signed char>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<char, unsigned char>);
```

To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types)

> [`char`] has the same representation and alignment as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, but is always a distinct type

Is it also guaranteed that `int8_t` and `uint8_t` are <s>defined in terms of the explicitly signed types</s> *not* defined in terms of `char`, and therefore also form a set of 3 distinct types with `char`?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<char, int8_t>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<char, uint8_t>);
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect standard to specify things which are hardly related, that would smell to me as over-specified. (and I somehow fail to see how int8/uint8 relate to char, except that char is highly likely represented by 8 bits too and you can cast between them safely, but none of that seems to me relevant to make the types same/non-same by standard.

Answer (score 8):

On your first point, yes, `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` must always be distinct types.

On the second point, `int8_t` and `uint8_t` might be or might not be the same type as a `char` (or its `signed` or `unsigned` variants); i.e. there is no guarantee for or against.

Answer (score 8):

The fixed-width types are *implementation-defined* aliases. The `(u)int8_t` types are NOT guaranteed to be aliases for any of the fundamental `char` types at all. They are only guaranteed to be (un)signed 8-bit integer types. They MAY be aliases for `(un)signed char`, or they MAY be aliases for vendor-specific types, such as `(un)signed __int8`. It is up to each compiler vendor to decide what aliases best suits their implementation.

Comment: I updated my question - what I'm hoping for is a guarantee that they are _not_ aliases of unqualified `char`, because if they are I cannot specialize a template for `char` without also matching one of those types.

Comment: @Eric: No, there's no such guarantee: `typedef char uint8_t;` would do if `char` is `unsigned`, although I'd conject that a *sensible* implementation would use `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;`.

Comment: To some extent, I'd argue it's the job of the standard to _require_ a sensible implementation :). I suppose this is a very small thorn to spend committee time on though...

Comment: @Eric what's the precise issue, if the `char` specialization covers also one of those two types? Does it clash, if you add another two specializations for `uint8_t` and `int8_t`? That would sound like real problem to me, but I would *expect* the compiler then to treat that ambiguity by checking for the specific type of the specialization and treating all three of them as different type. clang 8.0.0 seems to do that: https://godbolt.org/z/gphsmB  (for me this looks then as no-issue, because if your code wants to specialize for some type, it can)