# Why doesn't switching on a char value reach case 0xC2?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

Found a bug the code below, it parses C-string and is supposed to detect UTF8 characters:

```
char* pTmp = ...;
...
switch (*pTmp)
{
    case 'o':
    {
        ...     // works fine
        break;
    }   
    case 0xC2:
    {
        ...     // never gets triggered
        break;
    }
}
```

However `case 0xC2:` is never triggered.

My assumption is that `0xC2` is considered an `int` and therefore is 194 which is bigger than 127, the maximum value for `char` data type. So `-62 != 194`

Or may be there is some overflow or integer promotion is happening here.

Writing `switch ((unsigned char)*pTmp)` fixes the issue.

But I would like to clarify what is really going on here and what rules are applied.

I'm also open to changing the title, just nothing better came up in mind.

Comment: `case 0xC2:` is comparing with an `int` value decimal `196` but if `char` is `signed` then it is as you say, `-62.` You can verify that `0xC2` is type `int` with `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(0xC2));`. Aside: note that `'o'` is also an `int` value.

Comment: Copying and pasting from a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337217/difference-between-signed-unsigned-char): "C89 6.1.2.5 "There are three character types, designated as char , signed char, and unsigned char." C11 6.2.5p15 "The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called the character types." 6.2.5fn45 "char is a separate type from the other two and is not compatible with either""

Comment: I  tried to give it a better title based on how you phrased the question.

Comment: You could use a character constant, `'\xc2'`, so that it will have a character value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is `char` signed?

It is implementation specific if `char` has the same range as `signed char` or `unsinged char`.  In OP's case, `char` has the range [-128 ... 127], thus `case 0xC2:` is never matched.

---

> But I would like to clarify what is really going on here and what rules are applied.

The C standard library string functions have many parameters that are `char *`, yet those library functions internally act *as if* they are a pointing to `unsigned char` data

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type unsigned char (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value). C17dr § 7.24.1 3

To match that, OP's code should do likewise.  Doing so will also allow `*upTmp` to potentially match `0xC2`.

```
char* pTmp = ...;
unsigned char* upTmp = ( unsigned char*) pTmp;

switch (*upTmp)

   case 0xC2:
```

---

Alterative to using   *hexadecimal constant* `0xC2`, use a *character constant*: `'\xC2'` to match the range  of `char`. [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66835988/why-doesnt-switching-on-a-char-value-reach-case-0xc2/66836341#comment118143607_66836341).

---

[Pedantic]

"`switch ((unsigned char)*pTmp)` fixes the issue." -  it is close enough.

This "fix" works with 2's complements signed `char` as well as when the implementation defined `char` matches `unsigned char`.

For the remaining all but non-existent cases where `char` is signed and not 2's complement, fix is wrong as the characters should be accessed via `unsigned char *`, else the wrong value is used.

`switch (*(unsigned char *)pTmp)` works correctly in all cases.

Comment: If they are, for whatever reason, using `char` rather than `unsigned char`, they can use a character constant, as in `case '\xC2':` to get the corresponding `char` value. And using a character constant instead of an integer constant better expresses they are switching on a character value.

Answer (score 4):

I get this on adding `-Wall` [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6zKMf3as7)

```
warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type [-Wswitch-outside-range]
   14 |             case 0xC2:
```

So yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: This is relevant information, but your result is implementation-specific.