# C data types real life example

Tags: c, types, unsigned, signed

I am new to programming. While  i'm browsing for datatypes i found many data types,i understood all the other data types except **signed** and **unsigned** data types.
 can any one help me by giving real life examples for using signed,unsigned int,long,short data types.

Comment: what does realtime has to do with data type?

Comment: Does this question duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724242/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-uint-long-and-ulong)

Comment: This is not a tutorial service for the fundamentals of programming.  Visit MSDN for details on datatypes.  See [Ask] and take the [Tour] to learn what is acceptable to post here.  Also C and C# are 2  different languages

Comment: @Plutonix: MSDN is not a good reference for C code, as they don't support the standard. There are other sites which do, though.

Comment: I assume instead of "real time", you mean "real life examples" of when you could use "unsigned" vs "signed" integers.  An example of "unsigned" could be a variable specifying "years since birth" (i.e. years old)... You could safely use unsigned because "negative years since birth" is not possible.  Whereas, if an integer variable could represent either a positive value or a negative value, then it should be signed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `signed int` for some number that is conceptually a difference or can have a negative value for example the difference in distances.

Use `unsigned int` for some number that can only have positive value for example speed.