# How could I change code that decrements a number with x = += -(int)Settings.ABtn; so that x could never be less than zero?

Tags: c#

I have a property in my class:

```
public int Points { get; set; }
```

At some point it's being set to less than 0 but I am not sure where.  I suspect it is in this code:

```
phrase.Points += -(int)Settings.ABtn;
```

How could I change this so that Points could never be set to less than zero?

Comment: The question I have is, do you actually want the value to never go negative or do you want to fix a potential bug somewhere else where something is trying to add a negative value? Fixing at the setter level is going to answer your question, it would also tell you what is setting your value to less than zero if you throw an exception in your code when you receive a negative amount (you can then debug the caller and see what it was doing). Fixing what you "think" the bug might be isn't going to guarantee anything

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a lot of over thinking going on here, rather than answering the question as asked... Please confirm what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the property have a backing field and change the implementation:

```
private int _points;
public int Points 
{ 
  get 
  {
    return _points;
  }
  set
  {
    _points = value;
    if (_points < 0) 
      _points = 0;
  } 
}
```

One of the main points of properties vs fields is that you can change the implementation of a property without changing to the public interface.

To your caller it still looks like they are setting a value - you could also throw an exception if the value drops below zero if that's what you need.

Comment: There is another answer a lot similar which is even better in performance and posted earlier

Comment: I posted at pretty much the same time - also can you quantify how the other answer is "better in performance"? I'd suspect that both compile down to pretty similar instructions

Comment: phrase.Points -= (int)Settings.ABtn; if(phrase.Points < 0) phrase.Points = 0; // best performance

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis still not relevant and also not quantified therefore inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the value in the property's setter:

```
private int _points;
public int Points 
{ 
    get => _points; 
    set
    {
        _points = (value > 0) ? value : 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to check for < 0 first

Comment: @MarcoSalerno can you explain why you'd check for < 0 first? Are you prematurely optimising?

Comment: @Charleh yes, when optimising is like changing 2 characters, it is worth for me

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I don't think you are talking about optimisation here but code conventions and clarity which is subjective at best here.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main ways to approach this, as far as I can see it:

1) Make the variable type `uint` instead of `int`. `uint` is an unsigned integer number, ranging from 0 to 18446744073709551615 (You can read more about variable types in Wikipedia. I do recommend you to, since it is an important topic).
Moreover, you will get an exception when trying to make a `uint` less than 0, so you will be able to know where exactly something went wrong.

2) You can simply use the `Math.Abs()` method, which returns the absolute value of a number (e.g entering -9 will give back 9, and so would entering 9).

Just as a side note, you can make that line a bit simpler by changing it to:

```
phrase.Points -= (int)Settings.ABtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
phrase.Points = Math.Max(phrase.Points += -(int)Settings.ABtn, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this would work.  Let's see if anyone else can find any issues with your suggestion.

Comment: This isn't going to prevent the property from dropping below zero, it just prevents the caller from sending a negative value. If the question calls for the value to never drop below zero then the correct approach is to prevent this at the setter level, not fix all the callers. If you don't know where in the code the negative value is coming from but you want to ensure that the value never drops below zero, this code is only going to ensure that this particular line always results in a non-negative value.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `Points` property an `uint` like this :

```
public uint Points { get; set; }
```

`uint` means it's unsigned so it'll never go below 0, if you want to know more about the differences between `int` and `uint` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3724242/10352740)